# How could I use case within join and union?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

I have 2 tables:

**Matches**

```
CREATE TABLE rounds (
  `roundid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `roundname` VARCHAR(45) NULL);
```

**Rounds**

```
CREATE TABLE matches (
  `matchid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `matchwinner` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `roundid` INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_matches_rounds`
    FOREIGN KEY (`roundid`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`rounds` (`roundid`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

**Inserts**

```
INSERT INTO rounds (`roundid`, `roundname`) VALUES (1, 'Final');
INSERT INTO rounds (`roundid`, `roundname`) VALUES (2, '3rd place');
INSERT INTO matches (`matchid`, `matchwinner`, `roundid`) VALUES (1, 'fnatic', 1);
INSERT INTO matches (`matchid`, `matchwinner`, `roundid`) VALUES (2, 'astralis', 1);
INSERT INTO matches (`matchid`, `matchwinner`, `roundid`) VALUES (3, 'fnatic', 2);
INSERT INTO matches (`matchid`, `matchwinner`, `roundid`) VALUES (4, 'fnatic', 2);
INSERT INTO matches (`matchid`, `matchwinner`, `roundid`) VALUES (5, 'astralis', 1);
INSERT INTO matches (`matchid`, `matchwinner`, `roundid`) VALUES (6, 'astralis', 1);
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT 
    m.matchid,
    m.matchwinner Team,
    CASE r.roundname
        WHEN r.roundname = 'Final' THEN '1st'
        ELSE '2'
    END Place
FROM
    matches m
        JOIN rounds r ON m.roundid = r.roundid
WHERE
    r.roundname = 'Final' 
UNION SELECT 
    m.matchid,
    m.matchwinner Team,
    CASE r.roundname
        WHEN r.roundname = '3rd place' THEN '3rd'
        ELSE '4th'
    END Place
FROM
    matches m
        JOIN rounds r ON m.roundid = r.roundid
WHERE
    r.roundname = '3rd place';
```

I would like to know

- what places a particular team achieved (should probably use `HAVING m.matchwinner = 'fnatic'`)

MatchID - Team - Place
1 - fnatic - 1st
3 - fnatic - 3rd
4 - fnatic - 3rd

- what places all teams achieved

MatchID - Team - Place
1 - fnatic - 1st
2 - astralis - 1st
3 - fnatic - 3rd
4 - fnatic - 3rd
and so on

Don't understand why my query isn't working?

Comment: Please show us the result that you expect, as tabular text.

Comment: @GMB Now you can find it as well

Comment: Matches rounds rounds matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a join and conditional logic:

```
select 
    m.matchid,
    m.matchwinner team,
    case r.roundname
        when 'Final'     then '1st'
        when '3rd place' then '3rd'
    end place
from rounds r
inner join matches m on m.roundid = r.roundid
where m.matchwinner = 'fnatic' 
order by m.matchid
```

To get the same result for all teams, just remove the `where` clause.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6b25afa9198e79e964fefa1ebf2f215)**:

```
matchid | team   | place
------: | :----- | :----
      1 | fnatic | 1st  
      3 | fnatic | 3rd  
      4 | fnatic | 3rd
```

Comment: thank you for helping! I realized now that I'm not able to get 2nd and 4th place that I was trying for.

Comment: @worker: exactly, you cannot get that information. For this, you would need to store the loosing team as well.